# Design options: multi clusters, multi instances or multi availability groups

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, architecture, physical-design

We have a Microsoft platform, where within it, we have two sets of databases. One set of databases for the platform services etc. and one set of databases of more custom nature with some data that is loosely connected to other databases.

We would like to keep these database sets separate, as we would prefer that the platform set of databases has more performance than the other custom databases, but it is not the most important factor – high availability, stability, best practices and little complexity/ease of use is more important.

When we brainstorm this, we come up with three alternatives:
[image: options for platform]

- Option A: 2 clusters, 2 availability groups This is our current
  setup, obviously the best (?) but also most expensive and most time
  consuming to maintain
- Option B: 1 big cluster, 1 default instance, 2 availability groups
  Should be the easiest to maintain, but what options do we have to
  ensure our “preferred” AG (with platform databases) has highest
  availability?
- Option C: 1 big cluster, 2 instances, 2 availability groups With this
  option we can customize all the hardware resources per instance we
  want, but multi-instance, multi-AG also seems a bit complex to
  maintain

We would like to hear from others if they have opinions on the options above? What would you choose if money is no option? Any other options available?

Comment: It's not super clear what your different scenarios actually mean. E.g. I don't think Option B is possible if I understand it correctly - a minimum of 2 SQL Server instances is always needed to be able to use Availability Groups. What's your RPO & RTO? Are both sets of databases in the same SQL Server instance? Typically you setup the number of replica servers / instances you're comfortable with having ready for failover for a HA/DR scenario. For many people that's 2 (a primary and 1 secondary) because of cost. Others use a 3rd with async commit for improved performance by load-balancing reads.

Comment: Ah yes, for B, its means basically using the default instances and then having two separate AG.

Answer (score 1):

> We would like to keep these database sets separate, as we would prefer that the platform set of databases has more performance than the other custom databases, but it is not the most important factor – high availability, stability, best practices and little complexity/ease of use is more important.

The question is hard to answer because it can be very opinion based. I'm using your criteria as weighted in the following order from most important to least important.

1. High Availability
2. Stability
3. Simple Environment (non-complex)

Immediately #2 can't be used as is, due to stability being a function of too many factors. Thus, I'll continue with #1 and #3 only, in that order.

Out of the options you've presented (A, B, C) I would immediately throw out C.

> Option C: 1 big cluster, 2 instances, 2 availability groups With this option we can customize all the hardware resources per instance we want, but multi-instance, multi-AG also seems a bit complex to maintain

This setup violates #3 in the most egregious way. Having multiple instances leads to more complexity and less overall fairness. For example, a spike in IO in one instance can have a detrimental effect on the other instance as Windows (Linux is not an option) decides where that will be processed (cpu) and the drivers may or may not use some cpus more than others. This is just a single example; I'm not listed them all.

This leaves options A and B. so it really boils down to... Is the price point of option A a larger decision factor than the ability to control performance of individual databases? This is something you'll need to answer.

Other architectures exist, for example with using FCIs that could give you similar approaches without the need for AGs which, in general, has less complexity than AGs. Thus having two clusters and an FCI could be an option. A single cluster with 4 or more nodes with two different FCIs could be an option, where each node could only host one of the two instances on purpose (the other instances aren't installed), etc.